# I can't tick checkboxes in DataTable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

```
Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 75),
              child: PaginatedDataTable2(
                header: const Center(child: Text('Ürünler')),
                showCheckboxColumn: true,
                checkboxHorizontalMargin: 10,
                rowsPerPage: 8,
                source: _data,
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Stok Adı')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I added these codes in main.dart.

```
  class MyData extends DataTableSource {
  bool isChecked = false;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _data = List.generate(
      200,
      (index) => {
            "title": "Meyve",
            "price": " ",
            "kilo": " ",
          });

          

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(
        onSelectChanged: (bool? value) {
          isChecked = value!;
        },
        cells: [
          DataCell(Text(_data[index]["title"])),
          DataCell(TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('fiyat')),
          )),
          DataCell(TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text('kilo')),
          )),
        ]);
        

  }
```

Then I defined the above codes in a separate file named table.dart. I added the _data file as source to main.dart.
I guess I need to use setState but I couldn't call setState property in DataRow.

Comment: Can you include full sample widget that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you actually want to do. But it seems you are not providing the boolean value `isChecked` to the `showCheckboxColumn` field.

You can try this

```
Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 75),
              child: PaginatedDataTable2(
                header: const Center(child: Text('Ürünler')),
                showCheckboxColumn: isChecked, //<---- Here
                checkboxHorizontalMargin: 10,
                rowsPerPage: 8,
                source: _data,
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Stok Adı')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```